# Scaling and drawing a BufferedImage

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage

I have a customized `JPanel` with an `@Override` on the `paintComponent` method which takes an `BufferedImage` from a member variable and draws it. It works fine until I try to scale the image. I understand from reading that there are two different approaches. One is to use `Image.getScaledInstance` and the other is to create a `Graphics2D` with the dimensions of the scaled image. However, when I try to use either of these methods, I either get a completely white rectangle or I get nothing. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Code for the overridden method is below. Any advice would be appreciated. I am sure this is trivial but I can't see the issue.

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (img != null) {
        int imageWidth = img.getWidth();
        int imageHeight = img.getHeight();
        int panelWidth = getWidth();
        int panelHeight = getHeight();

        if(imageWidth > panelWidth || imageHeight > panelHeight){
            double aspectRatio = (double)imageWidth / (double)imageHeight;
            int newWidth, newHeight;

            // rescale the height then change the width to pre
            if(imageWidth > panelWidth){
                double widthScaleFactor = (double)panelWidth / (double)imageWidth;
                newWidth = (int)(widthScaleFactor * imageWidth);
                newHeight = (int)(widthScaleFactor * imageWidth / aspectRatio);
            }else{
                double heightScaleFactor = (double)panelHeight / (double)imageHeight;
                newHeight = (int)(heightScaleFactor * imageHeight);
                newWidth = (int)(heightScaleFactor * imageHeight * aspectRatio);
            }

            //BufferedImage scaledImage = (BufferedImage)img.getScaledInstance(newWidth, newHeight, BufferedImage.SCALE_DEFAULT);
            BufferedImage scaledImage = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, img.getType());
            int x = (panelWidth - newWidth) / 2;
            int y = (panelHeight - newHeight) / 2;

            //Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            Graphics2D g2d = scaledImage.createGraphics();
            //g2d.drawImage(scaledImage, x, y, this);
            g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight, null);
            g2d.dispose();
        }else{
            int x = (getWidth() - img.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - img.getHeight()) / 2;

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you want to scale your images? Just scale up / scale down? If that is the case, it's only a few lines of codes.

Comment: @user3437460 I only want to scale it down - i.e. if the image can be displayed on the panel without scaling then it doesn't happen - hence my if statement.

Comment: I think the main issue with the code you have posted is that it's overly complex, and therefore it's hard to spot the bug. But I'm confident the bug is that you never draw your scaled image to `g`. Ie. It may or may not scale correctly, but you will never ever see the results, as the result isn't painted.

Comment: @haraldK - I agree it is more complex than it needed to be. The fix given below shows the answer - if I don't cast `scaledImage` into a `BufferedImage` but just let it be an `Image` instead it all works fine. I have been doing some reading, but I am not sure why, given `BufferedImage` is a subclass of `Image`

Comment: You can't cast a base class to one of its subclasses, that will always give a `ClassCastException`. But as I say, the reason why your code above does "nothing", is that you don't include `g.drawImage(scaledImage, x, y, this)` anywhere (ie. you probably create a scaled image, but you never paint it to your component, so nothing is shown). Regardless of `Image` or `BufferedImage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whether it helps, because you havn't posted a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), but probably this will work better than your code.

```
Image scaledImage = img.getScaledInstance(newWidth, newHeight, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
int x = (panelWidth - newWidth) / 2;
int y = (panelHeight - newHeight) / 2;
g.drawImage(scaledImage, x, y, this);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have posted revised code at: https://github.com/jmcurran/jImageSorter/blob/master/src/jimagesorter/JImagePanel.java - as per above, I am unsure why using an `Image` works whereas a `BufferedImage` does not.

Comment: @JamesCurran I'm not sure, but method `getScaledInstance` can return another implementation of image. Also this image must be drawn into the `Graphics` object, which you get at the start of the method. In your code you draw the image into `Graphics` which created by the image.